# how to change dict of dataframes into one dataframe with multicolumns

Tags: python, pandas

As I got several items like:

```
item = pd.DataFrame({'item1': np.random.randn(3),
                     'item2': np.random.randn(3)},
                    index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

And then save them into one dict:

```
product = {'product1': item,
           'product2': item}
```

Now I want to change this dict into one dataframe, then I think in the form of multi columns is a better choice.
But how could I change it into this kind of result?

```
             product1           product2
      item1     item2    item1     item2
a  2.517220 -0.391607 2.517220 -0.391607
b  0.546790  1.533278 0.546790  1.533278
c  1.187944  0.981451 1.187944  0.981451
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
pd.concat({'product1': item,
           'product2': item}, axis=1)
#pd.concat(product, axis=1)
```